# How to use address function in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use VBA to dynamically add a formula to a few cells using the address function. When I run the following scripts I get a file explorer window that opens. I am not sure why that happens. What am I doing wrong?

Here is one of the solutions I tried:

```
Sub AddFormulas()

Set countBase = Sheet7.Range("CU2")
colCount = Sheet7.Range(countBase, countBase.End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count

Dim startCount As Integer
startCount = 98

    For i = 1 To colCount

        If IsNumeric(Sheet7.Cells(2, startCount + i)) Then
            Set bSum = Sheet7.Cells(3, colCount + startCount)
            Set bSpr = Sheet6.Cells(3, startCount + i)

            Sheet7.Cells(3, i).Formula = "=Sheet6!" & bSpr.Address() & "*" & "Sheet7!" & bSpr.Address()

         Else
            'Do some stuff
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I also tried this:

```
Sub AddFormulas()

Set countBase = Sheet7.Range("CU2")
colCount = Sheet7.Range(countBase, countBase.End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count

Dim startCount As Integer
startCount = 98

    For i = 1 To colCount

        If IsNumeric(Sheet7.Cells(2, startCount + i)) Then

            Sheet7.Cells(3, i).Formula = "=Sheet6!" & Cells(3, startCount + i).Address() & "*" & "Sheet7!" & Cells(3, colCount + startCount).Address() 

         Else
            'Do some stuff
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you rename your worksheets? You cannot use a codename in a worksheet formula but you can retrieve the name from the codename.

```
Sheet7.Cells(3, i).Formula = _
   "='" & Sheet6.Name & "'!" & bSpr.Address() & "*'" & Sheet7.Name & "'!" & bSpr.Address()
```

I've added wrapping single quotes to the worksheet names in case they contain spaces; there is no detriment if they do not.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped. I knew it was a simple fix. I can't believe I missed the name method!

Comment: @BWMustang13 technically `Name` is a *property*, not a method ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd go as follows

```
With Sheet7
    With .Range("CU2")
        colCount = .Range(.Cells, .End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
    End With

    startCount = 98

    For i = 1 To colCount

        If IsNumeric(.Cells(2, startCount + i)) Then
            Set bSum = .Cells(3, colCount + startCount)
            Set bSpr = Sheet6.Cells(3, startCount + i)

            .Cells(3, i).Formula = "=" & Sheet6.Name & "!" & bSpr.Address() & "*" & .Name & "!" & bSpr.Address()

        Else
            'Do some stuff
        End If
    Next i
End With
```